# C++ std::cin producing extra input

Tags: c++, std, cin

I am new to C++ and attempting to tackle some basic CodeJam problems. I am working on [Reverse Words](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/351101/dashboard#s=p1). I am running my code (in a unix environment) by piping in and out of the compiled executable:
`./compiled.program < input_file.in > output_file.out`

Here is my input (`input_file.in`):

```
3
this is a test
foobar
all your base
```

I would EXPECT the output:

```
test a is this
foobar
base your all
```

However, I get the output (`output_file.out`):

```
test a is this
foobar
```

(yes, that space in the beginning was intentional)

Here is my source code:

```
#include <string>                                                                                                           
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
      int number_of_cases;
      std::cin >> number_of_cases; 

      for (int i=1; i<=number_of_cases; i++) {
          std::cerr << i << std::endl;

          std::string input = ""; 
          std::getline(std::cin, input);

          while (true) {
              int pos = input.find_last_of(" ");
              if (pos == -1) {
                    std::cout << input;
                    break;
              }   
              std::cout << input.substr(pos+1)+" ";
              input.resize(pos);
        }   
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

The problem to me seems to be that another source of input (a blank source of input) is being read from between `3` and `this is a test` but for the life of me I cannot find out why. So that is my question: Why is this other source of input being read from?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Have you try to put a breakpoint on line `std::cin >> number_of_cases;` and to execute the whole program step by step, inspecting the variables?

Comment: Matt, I'm working on that right now! Shlublu, I am developing in Vim and compiling with g++ so I dont believe that is possible. Please correct me if I'm wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
std::cin >> number_of_cases;
```

reads in `3` but stops there, leaving the newline in the stream.

So for `i == 1`, `std::getline(std::cin, input);` just reads the newline from the end of the first line. Since this contains no spaces, you trigger `std::cout << input;` and then break down to `std::cout << std::endl`, generating your blank line.

Then the count of `3` runs out before getting to `all your base`.

To fix this you could do a dummy call to `getline` before entering the loop (this will have the bonus of consuming any trailing whitespace too).

Comment: How would you suggest doing a dummy call?

Comment: `std::string s; std::getline(std::cin, s);`

Comment: It would make the code easier to read and understand if you called `std::cin.ignore();` after `std::cin >> number_of_cases;`, rather than adding a call to `getline()`;

Comment: Is this the BEST way to accomplish this?

Comment: another option is `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`. Beauty is in the eye of the beholder, I prefer the dummy getline

Comment: @RichieHindle `cin.ignore()` only ignores a single character, however we need to be ignoring to the end of the line. (There could be whitespace after the `3` in general)

Comment: Although I am tending to lean towards Richie's alternative, this is the best answer for diagnosing the problem!

Comment: Also it'd be good to check that the read of `number_of_cases` didn't fail (as it would if the first word of the file was not a number), and that `std::getline()` within the loop didn't fail. Otherwise you will get bizarre output when the file is not containing the expected format

Comment: Yet another option would be to read the first line as a string (removing the need to `ignore`) , and then convert the string to int (exiting if that conversion fails)

Comment: @CorbinMc Do `std::cin >> std::ws` to clear the newline.

Answer (score 2):

In your program and sample input, when you input '3', I exactly input a character 3 and a character '\n'. So `cin` reads the character of integer only and leaves the '\n' in input buffer. `std::getline` reads the '\n' in the first iteration.